# How do I revert part of my changeset before uploading?

Tags: openstreetmap, josm

I've exported a changeset from the [Vespucci editor](https://vespucci.io/) to review in JOSM before uploading to OpenStreetMap. But it seems I've slipped at some point during my walk and offset a whole track.

How can I revert just this change within my changeset, short of manually editing the XML in the .osm file?

[image: Offset footpath]

Answer (score 2):

With [expert mode](https://josm.openstreetmap.de/wiki/Help/ExpertMode) enabled, it is possible to [purge](https://josm.openstreetmap.de/wiki/Help/Action/Purge) an element from a layer in JOSM. This removes it from the layer and means that there will be no change to that element when uploading your changes to the OSM database.

Make sure that the nodes are purged, not just the way, because the nodes' coordinates are what actually changes when you move a way.